# Eclipse Debugging: while continue after return statement?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I recently started working with Eclipse for Android development. When debugging through the code, I noticed one strange behavior (at least compared to Visual Studio): After hitting return statement in the middle of the function, it doesn't return immediately, but always jumps to the last return statement. For example:

```
String getTest(int i){
  if (i == 0)
     return "0";
  return "-1";
}
```

Given i = 0, after hitting the first return statement, instead of jumping out of this function, it moves to the next return statement. However, it does return "0", not "-1". So, why this dummy step? It is confusing to me. Can anybody explain why?

Comment: You are probably aware of this--but as a side note, better form (easier to read and less likely to introduce bugs) would include curly braces around the body of the `if` statement.  In this case, you can't `return` twice, so adding braces will not really have much effect.  Technically, if the `if` has a single line in its body, you can forgo the curly braces around that body--it is not incorrect.  On the other hand, if you inserted `i++;` on a line just before the second return statement, and you removed all indenting in this code, it would be ambiguous what was actually happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has to do with what exactly constitutes a "return" from a function. While this is platform dependent, a return typically has to:

- Copy a return code to a well known register (EAX in x86)
- Pop the return address off the activation record stack
- Reset the stack pointer (and base pointer)

Only the return value is different a compiler may choose to generate machine code (byte code in case of java) once and jump to it from different locations. Eclipse may be showing that jump.

Comment: So, is this eslipse issue or java issue? I've never seen it in Visual Studio using VC++ or C# or VB.

Answer (score 1):

This is just a visual thing in the eclipse debugger where it moves to the end of the function before finishing itself, no matter where the return statement was.
ie:

```
line:1    String method(String i){
line:2        return i;
line:3        extra code here...
line:4        extra code here...
line:5        extra code here...
line:6        extra code here...
line:7        return "fake return";
line:8    }
```

The debugger will always go from line 1 to line 2, then to line 8, then back to the code that invoked it in the first place, and it will always return i, never "fake return".

hope this helps.

Comment: I guess you wanted to say "then to line 7", right? Isn't confusing? I've never it in any other debugger.

Comment: i cant remember exactly whether its line 7/8, the principles the same though. if you added more code in between the two return statements, you would see it jump more than one line. If you added code inbetween the last return statement and the closing }, i doubt it would hit the second return.

Comment: Okay, if it jumps to line 8 after line 2, it's normal and it would be the same behavior in VS. But jumping to line 7 after line 2 is confusing to me. Anyway, I guess that's not so important.

Comment: I have not tried this example, but if that's what you're seeing, I think @Glenn.nz is correct.  I also believe that Firebug's debugger does the same thing, which was also confusing to me at first.